# How to edit default post settings

Tags: post-type

I want to delete content block and add custom fields for image, like on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5B4o.jpg).

I don't want to add custom content type, I just want to edit defalt post type.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the editor from the posts page and only display the custom fields box? Or do you simply want to remove the_content(); from the output?

Comment: Yes I want to remove/(If removal is not possible or too invasive I can hide) editor from post page and display the custom fields box. I know this is not safe but
A) is simpler than modification of a few plugins for handling cutom content type.
B) if I'll need  "normal posts" with ease I make content type for posts.
C) I do not want to give users the opportunity to write anything except post title

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [`manage_posts_columns` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Administrative_Filters), and also the [`manage_posts_custom_column`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) action.

[Here is a really old tutorial](http://scompt.com/blog/archives/2007/10/20/adding-custom-columns-to-the-wordpress-manage-posts-screen), linked from the Codex, that might be instructive. (Caveat: it's from 2007; some things might be out of date.)

#### Edit

The above hooks are for the manage posts screen. To remove/add meta boxes to the edit post screen, see [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and [`remove_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box), which can be invoked inside a callback function hooked into [`add_meta_boxes`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/add_meta_boxes).

Here's a [tutorial for customizing meta boxes](http://www.wproots.com/complex-meta-boxes-in-wordpress/) on the edit-post screen.

Answer (score 2):

I found something:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_editor_init');
function remove_editor_init() {
remove_post_type_support('post', 'editor');
}
```

And it's working for me ;) thanks guys